# Attempt to call upvalue 'Message' (a table value)

Tags: class, lua, discord, luvit, upvalue

So, I'm working on Discord API wrapper written in Lua, but there's an issue, I use [rxi's classic](https://github.com/rxi/classic) module for creating classes and objects, every class works fine, instead of the one class, Message, while trying to create a message in Interaction module.

Github repo : https://github.com/RealJace/discord.lua

Thank's for any help.

***NOTE : Every class that's being created is defined in original code but I had to remove them from codeblocks so StackOverflow let's me post this***
***NOTE 2 : Object class is the rxi's classic***

Comment: provide code that shows how Message is implemented.

Comment: Read the notes at the end please.

Comment: I read everything. the problem is that you cannot expect any help if you don't provide all information. The error message complains about an upvalue `Message` and from your post it is not clear how you define `Message`. you just call it. if you cannot post more code, ideally reduce your code to a [mcve]. if you don't know how, provide a repository or post it using pastebin or similar text sharing services.

Comment: You have to put the code in the question, not in pastebin. And not all the code that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I've added github repo link, modules are in classes folder

Answer (score 0):

Here you're calling `Message`:

```
self.message = Message(self.d["message"])
```

`Message` is a table value and does not have a metatable implementing the __call metamethod.

Either don't attempt to call it or ensure it can be called.

Comment: I'm using rxi's classic and it implements __call metamethod so yeah, and every other class works but not this one.

Comment: @RealJace well then you did not create Message properly. otherwise it would work.

Comment: how did I not create a message propertly? Everything works fine instead of this.